# Calculation of mean fundamental frequency of audio sample

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, frequency, frequency-analysis

I am working on a project to predict the gender of a user by taking live audio input from the user. While researching for this project I came across a dataset by kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/primaryobjects/voicegender, a CART logic was proposed where

```
if meanfun<0.14:
        if IQR>=0.07:
              return male

        else 
              return female
else 
        return female
```

I have tried to search for mean fundamental frequency but could not find any useful resources.
Please explain this concept and what is the difference between mean frequency and mean fundamental frequency? and also how to calculate it's value.

Answer (score 6):

I'll attempt to explain the concept...

Signals in general can be defined by being a sum of sine waves. As you may or may not know, a sine wave can be defined mathematically with the equation Asin(ωt+φ) where A is the amplitude, ω is the angular frequency, t is the time, and φ is the phase shift. ω can be further replaced by 2πf where f is frequency in Hz (the unit used in the documentation you linked). When they refer to frequency in this context, you could think of it as a sine wave component of the original/raw signal.

The definition of a sine wave is described in the wikipedia page, amongst many other resources, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave).

The audio signals you're looking at are complex signals likely with many sine waves involved. Fundamental frequency is referring to the lowest frequency that is detected ([wiki here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_frequency)). I imagine that the mean fundamental frequency is the average of all the frequencies that were detected in the signal.

The most common method to find the frequencies is by use of the Fast Fourier Transform ([FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)) - this changes the signal from time domain to frequency domain and you essentially get the break down of all the sine waves components that make up the original signal. Alternatively, you *could* get your hands dirty with peak detection - frequency is essentially number of times something occurs within some period of time so you could literally count number of peaks occurring over 1 minute (for example) to get your frequency value in Hz. I definitely don't recommend it for voice audio signals though.

To give you an idea of how a frequency value places within the audio spectrum, let's compare the musical note middle C to the A above it. Middle C is 261.626 Hz and A is 440.000 Hz ([source](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-notenames.htm)). As you can see, higher notes have higher frequencies.

What this project's logic is saying is that female voices are made up of higher frequencies than male voices (somewhat unsurprising). It's also saying that female voices on the lower frequencies are more tightly bound in the range of other frequency components than male voices (?) just based on the IQR > 0.07 - which is pretty interesting to know.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My major confusion is what is the difference between mean fundamental frequency and mean frequency? 
As in the dataset, both parameters were given.

Comment: Oh I see, I missed that one. They define 3 different frequencies: meanfreq, meanfun, and meandom. My guess is that meanfreq is the average across the entire frequency signal, meandom is actually what I described above as the average across dominant frequencies. meanfun is average fundamental frequency which is equivalent to average pitch which is a pretty complex/involved computation that can go much further than FFT. Here's a link to some pitch detection methods: http://sound.eti.pg.gda.pl/student/eim/synteza/leszczyna/index_ang.htm